# How to show that $Y$(martingale transform) has equal $L_2$ norm to $X$(martingale or supermartingale)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

$\mathbf{Definition}$:
We have that $C$ and $X$ are stochastic processes. The process $(C∘X)$ is martingale transform, where
$$(C∘X)_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n C_k(X_k-X_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^nC_kΔΧ_k,$$
when $n\geq1$ and $(C∘X)_0=X_0.$

$\mathbf{Theorem}$:
Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a history, the process $X$ satisfies $X\in \mathbf{F}$ and $C$ is a predictable process.

1)If in addition $0\leq C_n(\omega)\leq K$ and $X$ is a supermartingale, then $Y=(C∘X)$ is a supermartingale.

2) If in addition $|C_n(\omega)|\leq K$ and $X$ is a martingale, then $Y=(C∘X)$ is a martingale.

I want to show that $Y$ and $X$ have equal $L_2$ norm.

I've been studying this .pdf http://math.aalto.fi/teaching/stokanal/lecture2.pdf and i trying to understand how i am going to do that. The only thing that i think will help is that the norm of a martingale is a sub-martingale. But i have no idea how to continue.

Comment: I don't think that $X$ and $Y$ will have the same $L_2$ norm.  If you take $C=2$ then $C$ is clearly predictable and bounded, but $Y_n = 2 X_n$ so $\|Y_n\|_{L_2} = 2 \|X_n\|_{L_2}$

Comment: But $C$ is a stochastic process . Maybe i am missing something.

Comment: Right, I suppose I abused notation there.  I meant if you take $C_n(\omega)=2$ for all $n, \omega$.

Comment: So if your example doesn't violate anything i am guessing that you're correct. So by only taking $C_n(\omega)=1$ for all $n,\omega$ then we will have that $||Y_n||_{L_2}=||X_n||_{L_2}$?

Comment: That would certainly work, but I don't think that's the only way to make it work.  I'm not sure that you need them to have equal $L_2$ norms for the theorem proof, though.  I would try just computing $\mathbb{E}[Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ and checking the definition of a (super-)martingale.

Comment: Yeah, the proposition doesn't work all the time, so it's not worth it in my opinion to try and find all times that it works. My teacher in college made this proposition but he didn't give us the proof... he just stated it. I'll tell him that the proposition doesn't hold all the time. Thank you very much for helping me by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the theorem itself is definitely correct, it's just the part about the $L_2$ norms being equal that doesn't work.  Here is the proof for part i):

We want to show that $Y$ is a super-martingale, so we need to show $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|] < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] \le Y_{n-1}$ for all $n$.

First we will show $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|] < \infty$  (showing this one first because it makes sure that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ is well-defined).  We compute

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[|Y_n |]&= \mathbb{E}\left[\left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n C_k (X_{k}-X_{k-1}) \right\rvert\right] \\
&\le \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=1}^n |C_k|\cdot |X_{k}-X_{k-1}|\right] \\
&\le \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=1}^n K|X_{k}-X_{k-1}|\right] \\
&\le \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=1}^n K (|X_{k}|+|X_{k-1}|) \right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n K (\mathbb{E}[|X_k|] + \mathbb{E}[|X_{k-1}|]) < \infty.
\end{align*}

Now we need to show $\mathbb{E}[Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] \le Y_{n-1}$.  We compute

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] &= \mathbb{E}[Y_{n-1} + C_n(X_n-X_{n-1}) | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] & \\
&= Y_{n-1} + \mathbb{E}[C_n(X_n - X_{n-1})|\mathcal F_{n-1}] & \\
&= Y_{n-1} + C_n \mathbb{E}[X_n-X_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] &
\end{align*}

where we were able to pull $C_n$ out of the conditional expectation because $C_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ measurable.  Now since we were told $X$ is a super-martingale, we know $\mathbb{E}[X_n-X_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] \le 0$, and since $C_n(\omega) \ge 0$ for all $\omega$ this implies $C_n \mathbb{E}[X_n-X_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] \le 0$.  Therefore we conclude $$\mathbb{E}[Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]  = Y_{n-1} + C_n \mathbb{E}[X_n-X_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]  \le Y_{n-1},$$

so by the definition of a super-martingale, $Y$ is a super-martingale.

Comment: So for the second part we say that :$$E\left[ (C∘X)_{n+1}-(C∘X)_{n}|\mathcal{F}_n \right]=E\left[C_n(X_{n+1}-X_n)|\mathcal{F}_n\right]=C_n E\left[(X_{n+1}-X_n)|\mathcal{F}_n\right]=0 $$

Comment: That's pretty much it.  Possibly just a typo, but only thing is that it should be $C_{n+1}$ instead of $C_n$ (that's why it's important $C$ is predictable instead of just adapted).

Comment: Yeah that was a typo :D. By the way if you have time do you mind checking my question regarding the $L_2$ norm of $Y$ with  $\textbf {Itô′s isometry}$